# how to perform Junit test

Tags: java

How do I write Junit test for this code;

```
public String getDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");

        Date date = new Date();

    return dateFormat.format(date)
```

Comment: Do you have any code examples? Is your question how to write unit tests in general?

Answer (score 0):

It'll be far easier to test if you add a method that allows you pass in a Date:

```
public String getDate(Date date) {
    return (date != null) ? new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date) : "";
}

public String getDate() {
    return this.getDate(new Date());
}
```

Have your JUnit test pass in a fixed Date so it's repeatable and known to you:

```
@Test
public void testGetDate() {
    // setup
    String expected = "07/09/2018";
    Date testDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(expected);
    // exercise
    // Name of the class that you put the getDate() method into.   
    YourClass yc = new YourClass();
    String actual = yc.getDate(testDate);
    // assert
    Assert.assertThat(expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing a test is pretty straight forward and easy although as you can see there is a lot of repetition in the test and method under test. I would recommend to re-write your method under test.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    //arrange
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");

    //act
    String actual = getDate();

    //assert
    assertEquals(dateFormat.format(date), actual);
}

public String getDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");

    Date date = new Date();

    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```